# Find string in between in kibana elastic search with regex like in splunk

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

In **splunk**, we can filter out dynamic string in between two strings.

Say for example,

```
<TextileType>Shirt</TextileType>
<TextileType>Trousers</TextileType>
<TextileType>Shirt</TextileType>
<TextileType>Trousers</TextileType>
<TextileType>Shirt</TextileType>
```

The output I am expecting:

```
Shirt - 3
Trousers - 2
```

I am able to do this in splunk, easily.

Picture copied from Google (not exact one)
[image]

**How** can I achieve this in **Kibana** ?

Tried many ways, but not able to do any **regex** as per my need.

Note: Here's the example json query, in which I need to add regex. In this example, I am just trying to search for "Shirt" manually, which I am expecting to get dynamically.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "Shirt",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be a good case for the [new `wildcard` field](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field).

Answer (score -1):

Considering data is in the *sample* index, you can use a wildcard search:

```
GET /sample/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard":{
            "column2":"*Shirt*"
            }
        }
}
```

Notice how it only returns results containing keyword *Shirt*

[image]

If you are looking to clean the data, you'd need to run it through a logstash pipeline to strip the XML tags and leave you with the text.

Comment: Your code is to get all words with shirt keyword. My requirement is not that. Check `"The output I am expecting"` part in my post. Those inside the xml tags should print dynamically. Say string between `>` and `<`. Check my splunk query (in the screenshot)

Comment: You need to run it through a logstash pipeline to strip the XML tags and leave you with the text. Then you can apply aggregations. There's no magic formula there.

Comment: Oh ok. @Honky, thank you. How can I acheive that? Any website / video can be provided to me? I am new to Kibana.